# how To Get rid of Exponential format in datagridview when the number is very large

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

When the number is very large like :290754232, I got 2.907542E +08. in datagridview cell

I using vb.net , framework 2.0.

how can I get rid of this format?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try setting the DefaultCellStyle property of the DataGridView or DataGridViewColumn as suggested in the answers to your post on the MSDN forum https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b82596dd-d704-43af-a891-7d0b2a01f16b/how-to-get-rid-of-exponential-format-in-datagridview-when-the-number-is-very-large?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: I didn't know what format type should I use

Answer (score 0):

Set the default format for the column containing the large number like this:

```
myDataGridView.Columns("My Column").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D"
```

If you want commas (e.g. 290,754,232) use "N" instead of "D"

Comment: The data type is string . and this format doesn't affect the string. I have tried it.
I am getting data from google server as json format. and this column is stock volume. if volume is greater than 100 million , its comes as string (102M). so when parsing this json, if the data type of volume is integer or Long I will get an error since 102M is not a numeric. Because of that I used String datatype. Is there another way to stop E- format ?

Comment: @user3471633 If the value in the database is a string and the string looks like a number in scientific format, then you should probably get the string into the format you want before you store it in the database. In any case, it sounds as though this should be an Integer in the database.

Comment: There is no database , I am getting values from Google into Datagridview